# Check who downloaded the document - WSS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0

I am using WSS website and I have to check the username of the person who downloads the document. Programmatically or with some built in feature.

Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to check that you need either to enable AUditing (see here http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/) - but be aware that Viewing/Opening are in the same category as Downloading.